# ¿Como controlar una Exeption al Mandar a llamar los datos de Excel a C#?

Tags: c#

Les comento, Tengo un Método para importar los Datos de una `Hoja Excel` a una Tabla `DataGridView`

El Código donde mando a llamar al Método se encuentra en un `Button` y es el siguiente:

```
private void ImportarRenova_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
   {
      //DE ESTA MANERA FILTRAMOS TODOS LOS ARCHIVOS EXCEL EN EL NAVEGADOR DE ARCHIVOS
      Filter = "Excel | *.xls;*.xlsx;",

      //AQUÍ INDICAMOS QUE NOMBRE TENDRÁ EL NAVEGADOR DE ARCHIVOS COMO TITULO
      Title = "Seleccionar Archivo"
   };

   //EN CASO DE SELECCIONAR EL ARCHIVO, ENTONCES PROCEDEMOS A ABRIR EL ARCHIVO CORRESPONDIENTE
   if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
     //Aquí formateo los datos de la Columna prima Netal y Total para que no me aparescan con comas y vengan con solo 2 decimales.
     DGVAgregarRenovaciones.DataSource = ImportarDatos(openFileDialog.FileName);
     DGVAgregarRenovaciones.Columns["PRIMA_NETA"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##0.00";
     DGVAgregarRenovaciones.Columns["PRIMA_TOTAL"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##0.00";

  }
}
```

El Metodo el cual Importa los datos es el siguiente:

```
    DataView ImportarDatos(string nombrearchivo)
    {
        OleDbCommand consulta;
        //UTILIZAMOS 12.0 DEPENDIENDO DE LA VERSION DEL EXCEL, EN CASO DE QUE LA VERSIÓN QUE TIENES ES INFERIOR AL DEL 2013, CAMBIAR POR A EXCEL 8.0 Y EN VEZ DE
        //ACE.OLEDB.12.0 UTILIZAR LO SIGUIENTE (Jet.Oledb.4.0)
        string conexion = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0;'", nombrearchivo);

        OleDbConnection conector = new OleDbConnection(conexion);

        conector.Open(); 
        //DEPENDIENDO DEL NOMBRE QUE TIENE LA PESTAÑA EN TU ARCHIVO EXCEL COLOCAR DENTRO DE LOS []
        consulta = new OleDbCommand("select [POLIZA] as POLIZA_ANTERIOR,[POLIZA NUEVA] AS NUEVA_POLIZA,[IV] AS VIGENCIA_INICIAL,[FV] AS VIGENCIA_FINAL,[PRIMA NETA] AS PRIMA_NETA,[PRIMA TOTAL] AS PRIMA_TOTAL,[SERIE] AS NUMEROSERIE FROM [CONCENTRADO DE RENOV$]", conector);

        OleDbDataAdapter adaptador = new OleDbDataAdapter
        {
            SelectCommand = consulta
        };

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        
        adaptador.Fill(ds);

        conector.Close();

        ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.ItemArray.All(field => field == null || field == DBNull.Value || field.Equals(string.Empty) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.ToString()))).ToList().ForEach(row => row.Delete());
        ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();

        return ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
```

El detalle que tengo es que si el Archivo `Excel` no tiene las columnas que mando a llamar se me produce una `exeption` y se cierra el programa, Lo que busco es evitar eso y en vez de cerrar el programa mostrar un mensaje al usuario de revisar el archivo `excel` para que tenga las columnas necesarias.

De antemano Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregar un **try-catch** en el llamado de la función que realiza la recuperación de los datos, tal que si se produce una excepción allí puedas informar al usuario y evitar la terminación abrupta del programa por una excepción no controlada (que por lo que comentas es lo que está ocurriendo).

Algo como lo siguiente:

```csharp
    private void ImportarRenova_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ...
    
       //EN CASO DE SELECCIONAR EL ARCHIVO, ENTONCES PROCEDEMOS A ABRIR EL ARCHIVO CORRESPONDIENTE
       if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         //Aquí formateo los datos de la Columna prima Netal y Total para que no me aparescan con comas y vengan con solo 2 decimales.

         // MANEJAR LA EXCEPCIÓN, SI ES PRODUCIDA 
         try
         {
             // El programa intenta ejecutar esto
             DGVAgregarRenovaciones.DataSource = ImportarDatos(openFileDialog.FileName);
             DGVAgregarRenovaciones.Columns["PRIMA_NETA"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##0.00";
             DGVAgregarRenovaciones.Columns["PRIMA_TOTAL"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##0.00";
          } catch (Exception ex)
          {
              // Si falla entonces se ejecuta esto

              // Mostrar el mensaje, e.g. en un MessageBox
              MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error al leer el archivo"); // <-- AQUI EL MENSAJE PARA EL USUARIO
              // Trabajar la excepción  para registro y/o depuración
              Debug.WriteLine(ex);
          }
      }
    }
```

Si se busca ser más específico con los mensajes, entonces se pueden usar excepciones específicas en el **catch**, la clase **Exception** va a capturar todas si no existe un catch para esa en específico. Por ejemplo, si quisieras informar cuando no se pueda establecer la conexión o el problema sea relacionada a esto, alguna falla por el conector o no se cumple cierta configuración para algo, se puede entonces capturar mejor una [OleDbException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbexception?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) y brindar mayor orientación sobre el error.

Comment: Yo andaba peleando por no saber como agregar el try-catch en el método sin darme cuenta que podía haberlo agregado en la llamada... Muchas Gracias

Comment: Igual es una opción, lo puedes agregar a nivel método encerrando todo el código, pero no lo veo muy conveniente, a menos que por lógica de negocios la opción al encontrarse con un error sea mejor regresar una tabla vacía; de todos modos considero aún en ese caso puede ser mejor desde el llamado. Porque en ese escenario, ¿cómo sabría el usuario que pasó con sus datos, porqué no se cargó?